# How to set different images in the adapter of a cardview using recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder, cardview

I'm trying to use different images in different cardviews but the app displays on every card the image set in the xml layout.

[App appearance in emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVqAm.png)

XML code for the card

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
   android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iconImageView"
            android:src="@drawable/metodologia"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:paddingLeft="14dp"
            android:paddingRight="14dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Elements that are in the card

```
package com.example.recyclerviewcardview;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class ListElement implements Serializable {
    public Integer icon;
    public String topic;
    public String law1;

    public ListElement(Integer icon, String topic, String law1) {
        this.icon = icon;
        this.topic = topic;
        this.law1 = law1;
    }

    public Integer getIcon() { return icon; }

    public void setIcon(Integer icon) { this.icon = icon; }

    public String getTopic() {
        return topic;
    }

    public void setTopic(String topic) { this.topic = topic; }

    public String getLaw1() { return law1; }

    public void setLaw1(String law1) { this.law1 = law1; }
}
```

The adapter

```
package com.example.recyclerviewcardview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<ListElement> mData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Context context;
    final ListAdapter.OnItemClickListener listener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(ListElement item);
    }

    public ListAdapter (List<ListElement> itemList, Context context, ListAdapter.OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.mData = itemList;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {return mData.size();}

    @Override
    public ListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder (ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_element, parent, false);
        return new ListAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder (final ListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.bindData(mData.get(position));
    }

//    public void setItems(List<ListElement> items) {mData = items; }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView iconImage;
        TextView topic, law1;

        ViewHolder (View itemView) {
            super (itemView);
            iconImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iconImageView);
            topic = itemView.findViewById(R.id.topicTextView);
            law1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.law1TextView);

        }

        void bindData (final ListElement item) {
            iconImage.setImageResource(getIcon());
            topic.setText(item.getTopic());
            law1.setText(item.getLaw1());
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    listener.onItemClick(item);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is this, at the end of the adapter

```
 void bindData (final ListElement item) {
            //--------------> iconImage.setImageResource(getIcon());
            topic.setText(item.getTopic());
            law1.setText(item.getLaw1());
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    listener.onItemClick(item);
                }
            });
        }
```

I can't make the getIcon() method to work

```
iconImage.setImageResource(getIcon());
```

How could I do it? Thanks.

Comment: How are you setting icon's in model?

Comment: Add your activity code

Comment: @SandeshKhutalSaheb don't think the activity/fragment code will make much of a difference here, the logic OP is looking for will mostly be in the adapter, right ? they just need to include what's currently there and what isn't working

Comment: You should invoke the method on the `item` object: `iconImage.setImageResource(item.getIcon());`

Comment: Thank you all. @Ipizzinidev it is the answer, I forgot the item object. Thank you very much. I think you have to post the answer and I mark it as a green tick, right?